# How to truncate characters in between of a large column in tsv/csv?

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a csv file:

```
1,abcde aa aaaa aaa aaaa abcde,4
2,efghi ooo oooo ooo oooo efghi,5
```

I need it to truncate the second column with initial and last five characters and fill with three dots. How to acheive this?

```
1,abcde ... abcde,4
2,efghi ... efghi,5
```

Comment: Can any of the fields in your CSV file contain embedded commas, newlines, or other quoted fields, or is it a "simple CSV" file?

Comment: If your input always looks as posted there's simpler solutions than counting 5 chars at the start/end of the 2nd field, e.g. `sed 's/ .* / ... /'`. If it doesn't always look like that then you should include those cases so we can test with them and include cases where the 2nd field is shorter than 10 chars (so we can see how to handle potential duplication of chars in the output), where the non-blanks at the start/end of the 2nd field are shorter and longer than 5 chars, etc.

Comment: (1) Examples that use the same string (e.g., ```abcde```) multiple times are confusing.  People can assume that your input always looks like that, and then write answers that work ***only** if*  your input looks like that.  If your input will always look like that, please say so.  (For example, write “The second comma will *always* be preceded by the same five characters as came after the first comma.” or “The second field will always begin and end with the same five-letter word.”)  Otherwise, please show more realistic examples. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (2) You say “fill with three dots”, but then you show filling with space + 3 dots + space.  Questions are often downvoted and deleted for inconsistencies like that.  (3) Can there ever be more than three “columns” (fields)?  Some of us have written answers that assume that there are only two commas in each line.  (4) Also, please show what to do if the fifth, or the fifth-to-last, character is a space; for example, ```17,Rama ooo ooo ooo prak asha,42```. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (5) And, in case this isn’t clear from the other comments, please show what to do if the first or last word in the second column is *more* than five letters; e.g., `83,realistic ooo oooo example,95`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I feel raku example covers most of case, which may arise in future. I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The `sed` solution is

```
sed -E 's/(.*,.{5}).*(.{5},.*)/\1...\2/'
```

This will leave the input untouched
if the second “column” (field) is nine characters or fewer,
but will inject “`…`” even if it is exactly ten characters
(even though it won’t be taking the place of any characters):

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `9,abcdefghi,z` | `9,abcdefghi,z` <sup>(no change)</sup> |
| `10,abcdefghij,z` | `10,abcde...fghij,z` <sup>(note that this is ***longer*** than the input.)</sup> |

[cas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/685988/80216#686007) suggests explicitly checking whether
the second field is long enough to make substitution worthwhile. 
Since my answer is doing what the question ***says*** (injecting three dots)
and not what it shows (injecting space + three dots + space,
or, alternatively, preserving spaces from the input),
we get a benefit if there are at least four other characters
between the first five and the last five. 
We can handle that with this command:

```
sed -E 's/(.*,.{5}).{4,}(.{5},.*)/\1...\2/'
```

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `10,abcdefghij,z` | `10,abcdefghij,z` <sup>(no change)</sup> |
| `13,abcdefghijklm,z` | `13,abcdefghijklm,z` <sup>(still no change)</sup> |
| `14,abcdefghijklmn,z` | `14,abcde...jklmn,z` <sup>(this is one character shorter than the input.)</sup> |
| `20,abcdefghijklmnopqrst,z` | `20,abcde...pqrst,z` |

`.{4,}` matches 4 or more characters. 
Naturally, you can change the `4` to any non-negative integer. 
For example, to duplicate cas’s answer
with the suggested `min=20`, use `.{11,}`.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't worth doing unless $2 is longer¹ than what you're going to truncate it to (which is 15 characters: 5 chars + space + 3 dots + space + 5 chars), so:

```
$ awk -F, '
  BEGIN {OFS=FS; min=15};
  length($2) > min { $2 = substr($2,1,5)  " ... " substr($2, length($2)-4) }1' input.csv 
1,abcde ... abcde,4
2,efghi ... efghi,5
3,short field,5

$ cat input.csv 
1,abcde aa aaaa aaa aaaa abcde,4
2,efghi ooo oooo ooo oooo efghi,5
3,short field,5
```

Alternatively, calculate `length($2)` only once for each input line:
(also shows alternate method of setting OFS and min)

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v min=15 '
  { L=length($2) };
  L > min { $2 = substr($2,1,5)  " ... " substr($2, L-4) }1' input.csv
```

---

¹ and probably isn't worth doing unless it's significantly longer than that, so probably a minimum of ~ 20 chars.

Comment: FYI: I modified my answer to reference yours and copy one of your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

With your current example all you need is:

```
$ sed 's/ .* / ... /' file
1,abcde ... abcde,4
2,efghi ... efghi,5
```

or if you REALLY need to just operate on the 2nd field then:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/ .* /," ... ",$2)}1' file
1,abcde ... abcde,4
2,efghi ... efghi,5
```

If that's NOT all you need then edit your question to show more truly representative sample input/output including cases that doesn't work for.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's/ \, <( (<alnum>**5) .* (<alnum>**5) )> \, /$0 ... $1/;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's/ \, <( $<head>=[<alnum>**5] .* $<tail>=[<alnum>**5] )> \, /$<head> ... $<tail>/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
1,abcde aa aaaa aaa aaaa abcde,4
2,efghi ooo oooo ooo oooo efghi,5
```

Sample Output (both code examples above):

```
1,abcde ... abcde,4
2,efghi ... efghi,5
```

The above answers use the **Raku** Programming Language, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. Both answers above tacitly assume that the first 5 characters to the right of the column_1 comma are `<alnum>` (alphabetic plus underscore plus `<digits>`). See code below for how to handle a wider variety of characters.

Raku uses a new regex engine, designed to be more powerful as well as more readable. In the first example numbered captures are used (`$0`, `$1`), while in the second example named captures are used (`$<head>`, `$<tail>`). Highlights of the code above include 1) sensible escaping of non-alnum characters like `\,` (so you don't have to guess), grouping regex 'atoms' with `[ … ]` square brackets, capturing with `( … )` parens, numbering captures starting from `$0`, using `**min..max` as a general quantifier (example: `**5`),  and delineating the extext of the match-object with `<( … )>` capture markers, so the (external-to-the-match-object) commas don't inadvertantly get deleted.

Note, the above answer(s) use Raku's built-in `<alnum>` character-class, which consists of `<alpha>` (alphabetic, underscore) plus `<digits>`. However you may desire to truncate a wider variety of characters. You could try substituting the `<alnum>` built-in character class with the bespoke (custom and/or enumerated)  character class: `<+[\S]-[,]>`. The `<+[\S]-[,]>` custom character class will accept `+[\S]` any non-whitespace character (like decimal points in numbers) minus the comma, which is subtracted out using `-[,]`.

Below gives a reasonable result, e.g. lines 1 and 2 are appropriately shortened, while line_3/column_2 (only 4 non-comma characters long) is too short to be truncated further. (Thanks to @cas for the "short field" inspiration):

```perl
raku -pe 's/ \, <(( <+[\S]-[,]>**5) .* ( <+[\S]-[,]>**5 ))> \, /$0 ... $1/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
1,$2.37 aa aaaa aaa aaaa abcde,1_end
2,##IN: ooo oooo ooo oooo efghi,2_end
3,#OUT, ooo oooo ooo oooo efghi,3_end
4,short field,4_end
5,thin ice,5_end
```

Sample Output:

```
1,$2.37 ... abcde,1_end
2,##IN: ... efghi,2_end
3,#OUT, ooo oooo ooo oooo efghi,3_end
4,short ... field,4_end
5,thin ice,5_end
```

https://raku.org